# fiddler POST Token Authentication HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request web api

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I just started up a WebApi project in Visual Studio 2015 that uses Individual Account authentication and all default settings/classes.  I added only an html page for entering a username and password which successfully stores in a sql server db.  Everything is all default.

Next I try to do a post from fiddler using Token authentication and receive the following:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

and in the Response body I see this in RAW mode

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcbXlTdHVmZlxBc3BfTVZDX3N0dWZmXEdpdEh1Yl9zYW1wbGVzXEVtcGxveWVlU2VydmljZXNQcm9qZWN0c1x0ZXN0V2ViQXBpXHRlc3RXZWJBcGlcdG9rZW4=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 01 Dec 2017 19:47:24 GMT
Content-Length: 87

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The user name or password is incorrect."}
```

Here is what I enter in Composer:

POST  | http://localhost:61384/token

Host: localhost:61384

Content-Length: 55

And in the Request Body I enter this:

username=da@da.com&password=Daa123*&grant_type=password

I tried adding Content Type: application/........

but still got the same error response

Do I need to use a different grant_type maybe?  Or is there some configuration thing in fiddler I need to address/modify?

I ***AM*** able to post to the DB from fiddler if I don't use Token authentication.  But how can I do it using Token authentication?

Comment: I have moved along with my webapi project and added a login html page and also a controller and an EF6 entity with some fake data.  The controller is decorated with [Authorize] which requires the login. this all works, and interestingly -- in fiddler, if I issue a GET in parsed and add Authorization: Bearer the_token_which_was returned_in_the_login_page_jasdfasdfasdf    it DOES retrieve the data in fiddler.  So the issue must be in fiddler for the POST with Token Authentication because the everything works OK from the project and token works with GET in fiddler.  How to get POST to work in fid